# how to implement and which Audio, video chat with file transfer for mywebsite using php

Tags: php, video, livechat

I have to implement chat application to mywebsite using php.
Chat has the features like audio, video, and file transefer.

so please give reply for this,

Thanks,

Comment: I do not really understand if you want to be able to send video & audio files or to call with audio and video webcam?

Answer (score 1):

As a developer of video chat apps for several years (http://avchat.net) I think I can make a few calculated comments on this topic:

1) There are 2 big types of chat apps for websites out there: Group chats (IRC style) and Instant Messengers (Facebook chat is the best example here)

2) The text chat part can be done purely with HTML/JS on the client and Php/ASPX on the server  however these solutions will tend to put some load on your server because of the constant pooling. One solution is to use an XMPP/Jabber server and another is to use Erlang server side (Facebook uses it).

3) For audio and video chat you will need a media server (FMIS from Adobe is $4500, Wowza is $995, Red5 is open source and free) . The client will also have to be done in flash (at least the video/audio part).

4) There are also media server hosting companies (http://influxis.com) and Amazon EC2 offers servers with both Wowza and FMIS pre-installed.

5) Flash aso allows you to do peer 2 peer video but it's only good for **1 to 1** or **1 to huge audience** scenarios. And you still need a p2p capable media server (FMES).

Answer (score 0):

Mmm.. building one application like that is not easy at all, and you won't only need PHP.

I guess you are looking for an applet or script that is already implemented.

I just know some JS scripts that can be embedded into your website, but just chat [not audio, video, and else..]

Try this:

http://www.sitescripts.com/JavaScript/Chat_and_Instant_Messaging/

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to be able to send files you need to upload them to the server, I guess with AJAX to make it smooth. For that you could use http://www.uploadify.com/

If you want audio and video chat too you will need Flash - no way of escaping that. It is not easy at all. Maybe http://avchat.net/ would be what you want.